# POST Request using req.write() and req.end()

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do `HTTP POST` using the the [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module from a node server to another server.

My code looks something like,

```
var req = request.post({url: "http://foo.com/bar", headers: myHeaders});
...
...
req.write("Hello");
...
...
req.end("World");
```

I expect the body of the request to be `"Hello World"` on the receiving end, but what I end up with is just `""`.

What am I missing here?

Note: The ellipsis in the code indicates that the `write` and the `end` might be executed in *different process ticks*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make the code written in the question here valid and work as expected by modifying the [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module a bit.

I noticed a block of code in `request`'s [`main.js`](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/07135d542ea6c4578c26310ae0ffe6f2c6933b7d/main.js) in the [`Request.prototype.init`](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/07135d542ea6c4578c26310ae0ffe6f2c6933b7d/main.js#L106) function (at [line 356](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/07135d542ea6c4578c26310ae0ffe6f2c6933b7d/main.js#L356)),

```
process.nextTick(function () {
    if (self._aborted) return

    if (self.body) {
      if (Array.isArray(self.body)) {
        self.body.forEach(function (part) {
          self.write(part)
        })
      } else {
        self.write(self.body)
      }
      self.end()
    } else if (self.requestBodyStream) {
      console.warn("options.requestBodyStream is deprecated, please pass the request object to stream.pipe.")
      self.requestBodyStream.pipe(self)
    } else if (!self.src) {
      if (self.method !== 'GET' && typeof self.method !== 'undefined') {
        self.headers['content-length'] = 0;
      }
      self.end();
    }
    self.ntick = true
  })
```

I'm now overriding this function call by adding a new option (`endOnTick`) while creating the request. My changes: [Comparing *mikeal/master* with *GotEmB/master*](https://github.com/GotEmB/request/compare/master).

Comment: I'd like to know if I'm breaking anything in `Request` by doing so. Should that be a new question?

Answer (score 1):

As 3on pointed, the correct syntax for a POST request is

```
request({ method:"post", url: "server.com", body:"Hello World"}, callback);
```

You also have a convenience method:

```
request.post({ url: "server.com", body:"Hello World"}, callback);
```

But from your question it seems like you want to stream:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('file');

stream.write('Hello');
stream.write('World');

fs.createReadStream('file').pipe(request.post('http://server.com'));
```

Update:

- You may break the chunks you write to the stream in any way you like, as long as you have the RAM (4mb is peanuts but keep in mind that v8 (the javascript engine behind node) has an allocation limit of 1.4GB I think);
- You may see how much you "wrote" to the pipe with `stream.bytesWritten` where `var stream = fs.createWriteStream('file')` as you see in the piece of code above. I think you can't however know how much the other end of the pipe got, but bitesWritten should give you a pretty decent approximation.
- You can listen to the `data` and `end` events of both `stream` and `request.post('http://server.com')`

Comment: Well I am basically streaming. But I'd like to break apart the stream into chunks of max 4MB. And I'd also like to know how much has been streamed. Is it possible to listen to the `data` and `end` events while using `pipe`?

Comment: I updated my answer with 3 bullet points answering those questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are getting missed Request http.clientRequest/http.serverRequest

If you want to make a post to a server with request what you want to do is something like

```
request({ method:"post", url: "server.com", body:"Hello World"}, callback);
```

Comment: Ok, so using the `request` that you are talking about, you cannot do what I'm trying to do? Why I'm not using what you suggested is because I need to be able to add content to the body across processTicks and be able to send the request with that `end`.

Comment: The whole point of request is to not have to it this way because it is a pain. You may want to use the core module: http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_http_clientrequest

Comment: I'm trying that now: [http.request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)